# Reactjs: How to implement Text count in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Implementing Text character counts in Reactjs. The code below counts words when values are inputted in the form.

Now I have a requirement to make  it count character texts.

How do I make it to count text characters and not words and then return an error message is text exceeds. For example **Food** has **four** character text.

**Below is the code**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
class TextCounter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstValue: "",
      secondValue: "",
      needtexts: 13,
      textCount: "",
      limtexts: null
    };
    this.textcountHandle = this.textcountHandle.bind(this);
  }


  textcountHandle(event) {

    const textCount =
      event.target.value === "" ? 0 : event.target.value.split(" ").length;
    this.setState({
      secondValue: event.target.value,
      textCount: textCount,
      limtexts:
        this.state.needtexts - textCount < 0
          ? this.state.secondValue.length
          : null
    });
  }

  render() {
    var result = this.state.needtexts - this.state.textCount;
    let tooManyChars;
    if (result < 0) {
      const tooManyCharStyle = {
        color: "red"
      };
      tooManyChars = (
        <p style={tooManyCharStyle}>
          You exceeded the maximum number of Text characters!!
        </p>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>

          <p>You have maximum of {result} Texts characters to inputs</p>
          <textarea
            type="text"
            value={this.state.secondValue}
            onChange={this.textcountHandle}
            maxLength={this.state.limtexts}
          />
          {tooManyChars}

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're splitting the input on the `" "` character, which is used to split at word boundaries.

Just take the length of the string input, that will give you the number of characters.

```
const textCount = event.target.value.length;
```